# How do I prevent google from giving me an "id" cookie in Firefox?

Tags: web, browsing

I run Mozilla Firefox with Private Browsing, so each time I start a browser there are no cookies.

Unfortunately for me, the first chance it gets, google gives me an "id" cookie, since it notices there isn't one.

I have clicked on "opt out" more times than I can count, and I am sick of clicking on it but the cookies always come back.

Is there a Firefox extension which will, once and for all, stop the "id" tracking cookies from entering my browser?

I don't want to switch to Google Chrome.

Comment: I will point out that this has now become more important to me because I got an AdSense targeted ad that could only have come to me if computers were reading my Gmail.  Which, of course, they are doing, all the time.  But the creepiness factor has now gone too far, and I wish to "fight back".

Comment: I know how you feel, take a look at my answer so see how you can disable their cookies.

Comment: For Firefox extensions, see https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/extensions/privacy-security/ There is e.g., Ghostery, BetterPrivacy,  ...

Comment: **Stop using Google.** They are using those cookies to track you and sell your pesonal info to spammers. Switch to another search engine, such as [Bing](http://bing.com).

Comment: Surprised no one had advised using NoScript, I have switched to Startpage...https://startpage.com/

Answer (score 3):

The ultimate solution would be to just not allow cookies at all. You don't need a third-party extension to accomplish cookie blocking. You can disable Firefox cookies like so:

1. At the top of the Firefox window, click on the Firefox button (it's called the Tools menu in Windows XP) and then click Options
2. Select "*Privacy*" tab
3. Set the dropdown box "*Firefox will*" to "*Use custom settings for history*"
4. Remove the check from "*Accept cookies from sites*"

Although this will stop the google cookie, it will also disallow other cookies. To only disallow cookies from specific domains (like google.com), click "*Exceptions...*" and add google.com to the list of disallows domains.

[image: Screen shot]

[Picture source](http://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/Enabling%20and%20disabling%20cookies)